# how i set only one table row dropdown in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I am using reacts to develop a website. I need to put a dropdown in only one column.

```
 const tableConfigs = [
    {
       name: "return or not",
       column: {
       args: { dataIndex: ["product", "uuid"] },
        },
      },
      {
    name: "productid",
    column: {
      args: { dataIndex: ["product", "uuid"] },
    },
  },
 ];
    
    const AllDetails = () => {
    return (
           <Records
              apis={UserOrderItemAPI}
              configs={{
                modal: modalConfigs,
                other: otherConfigs,
                table: tableConfigs,
              }}
              title="all_Details"
            />
          );
        }
        export default AllDetails;
```

I have this type of code. I want to add dropdown in a one column like this code:

```
{
    name: "image",
    column: {
      args: {
        dataIndex: ["product", "image"],
        render: (src) => (
          <Image src={src} height="40px" referrerPolicy="no-referrer" />
        ),
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for creating a select options. I hope it's use full for you.

```
  import { Select } from 'antd';
        const { Option } = Select;
        const handleChange = (value) => {
          console.log(value); // { value: "no", key: "no", label: "NO" }
        };



    {
        name: "return or not",
        column: {
          args: { dataIndex: ["product", "uuid"],
            rander: (select) => (
              <Select labelInValue defaultValue={{value: 'no', label: 'NO',}}style={{width: 120,}} onChange={handleChange}>
                <Option value="no">NO</Option>
                <Option value="yes">YES</Option>
              </Select>
               )
            }
          },
        },
```

Comment: can i add already exist component in code.

Comment: YES , you can add your exist component of select in place of rander function.